# "Tell somebody" in direct discourse (narration)

Tags: word-choice

When using direct discourse (narration), can I use "**tell**" before quotation marks? Today I used it in English composition and my teacher **said to me**, "You should use '**say to somebody**' before quotation marks and you cannot use '**tell somebody**'. It is only used in indirect discourse." I think "**tell**" is right and other verbs are to be accepted in direct discourse but I'm not sure.

I wrote: *(When I see my pet dog coming to me with his tongue stuck out) I always want to tell him, "Hey, my best friend, you're so pleased, aren't you?"*
My teacher corrected: *I always want to say to him,*

Comment: I think this question would benefit from an example sentence or two. What did you put, and what did your teacher want you to write?

Comment: I told the boy,  "Sit down right away or you will be in big trouble. I said to the boy, "Sit down right away or you will be in big trouble". Please note: whether you use I told the boy or I said to the boy, that usually comes at the end of a sentence in a dialogue.

Comment: The use of "tell" with a question (as you have here) isn't right.  You don't tell someone a question - you **ask** them a question, or you **say** something to them (which could be a question - "said" is more general).  Obviously this question is rhetorical but I don't think that matters.

Comment: I think that you **could** say *I always want to tell him "You're my best friend!"* - note this isn't a question now.

Comment: I agree with @MaxWilliams, unfortunately the only thing somehow resembling a reference was [this.](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/cw-say-tell.htm) It includes *tell* not working with questions.

Comment: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tell) licenses the use of 'tell' as both a report verb and a quotative verb: << **tell** verb (SPEAK)

​
A1 [T] to say something to someone, often giving them information or instructions:
...
[ + obj + (that) ] Did you tell anyone (that) you were coming to see me? // 
[ + obj + speech ] "I'm leaving you," she told him.
... >>

Comment: Never abbreviate "somebody" to "sb" if you want anyone to treat you seriously. Write the whole word.

Comment: @curiousdannii Interesting – I saw the same caution used about the use of obvious user-names the other day.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is correct. When you "tell" the subject something, it is not a conversation, it is an imperative. I can tell you *Go to the store.*  I do not *tell* you "How was your day?", I *ask* you. A question always initiates a conversation; even if the listener is a dog who probably can't respond in English.

Where there is some ambiguity is if it's unclear whether or not I am starting a conversation, or merely recounting facts. I may say to my spouse, "I had a terrible day" and hope that she responds sympathetically. Or I may tell her "I had a terrible day" to explain my curt behavior, not expecting a response.

Comment: +1 for noting that the difference between *tell* and *say to* is not direct versus indirect as the OP indicates, but rather between declarative or imperative versus interrogatory.

Comment: I don't disagree, but ELU prefers answers supported by relevant credible references.